# No file provider has been configured to process the supplied file

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-2.1

I am using Single Page Application with .Net core 2.2. I have following in my startup.cs.

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
                    name: "spa - fallback",
                    defaults: new { controller = "CatchAll", action = "Index" });

            });
```

But having following

```
public class CatchAllController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return File("~/index.html", "text/html");
        }
    }
```

gives me following error.

**No file provider has been configured to process the supplied file**

I was following following article (one difference. article uses API project. I had taken angular project).

https://www.richard-banks.org/2018/11/securing-vue-with-identityserver-part1.html

Comment: Does your project have static files enabled?

Comment: I have these 2 in my startp.cs => app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

Answer (score 3):

I was just fighting this exact problem. Even though the `File()` method claims to take a "virtual path" I could never get it to load the file without the error you're getting. Here's what I ended up piecing together after reading a number of different posts.

```
[Route("[controller]")]
public class DocumentationController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _env;

    public DocumentationController(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        _env = env;
    }

    [HttpGet, Route("apiReference")]
    public IActionResult ApiReference()
    {
        var filePath = Path.Combine(_env.ContentRootPath,
            "Controllers/Documentation/My Document.pdf");
        return PhysicalFile(filePath, "application/pdf");
    }
}
```